# The suggested-edits flag icon should reflect what my client knows for sure.

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits, top-bar

The server accepts review submission input and is assumed (known?) to then act in a valid manner, and to communicate to the client in the HTTP response whether everything went right. However, the suggested-edits flag icon in the top bar does not reflect the potentially new situation, unless I "refresh" the page (To anywhere), and yet the badge progress bar **does**.

I *did* notice the suggested-edits flag icon disappear sometimes (No "refreshing"), which complicates things, and is not yet very relevant...

It think it would make much more sense, if I didn't see that I still have suggested edits, when in fact I have none, this being known to both parties.